# Refer to a sheet on a non-active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I can't figure it out what is the right way to reference a sheet on a workbook that is not active.

I have the following code:

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim firstEmpty As Integer
Dim trackBook As Workbook
Dim trackSheet As Worksheet       

Set trackBook = Application.Workbooks.Item("Tracking Sheet.xlsx")
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

And now I want to refer to a sheet on trackBook. I tried to set a variable:

```
Set trackSheet = trackBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
```

And I get run-time error 9: subscript out of range.

I also tried to do it without setting a worksheet variable:

```
firstEmpty = trackBook.Worksheet("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

and I get run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

What am I doing wrong in both cases and I should this be done?

Comment: [Here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Subscript_Out_of_Range) you find the typical situations which lead to run-time-error 9

Comment: when you say the workbook isn't active, it's vague.. Is the workbook open? If it is/isn't determines how to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is correct:

```
Set trackSheet = trackBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
```

and the subscript out of range error suggests the workbook in question doesn't contain a worksheet named "sheet1".

This syntax is incorrect:

```
firstEmpty = trackBook.Worksheet("sheet1").Range...
```

and the error message indicates that the "trackBook" object doesn't contain a property or method `Worksheet` (should be plural: `Worksheets`).

I would run under the debugger, break on the line `Set trackSheet = trackBook.Worksheets("sheet1")`, and examine the Worksheets property in the Watch window.  In particular, examine the names of each worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

*Work with [Workbooks.Open method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Book1.xlsm")

    Debug.Print xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

        xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it's a little longer, but it has error handling for `Workbook` and `Worksheet` scenarios.

```
Dim trackBook As Workbook
Dim trackSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, firstEmpty As Long


' set the workbook object (if workbook is already open)
On Error Resume Next
Set trackBook = Workbooks("Tracking Sheet.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If trackBook Is Nothing Then ' workbook is not open >> open it
    trackBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\YourEntirePath\Tracking Sheet.xlsx")
End If

' set the worksheet object
On Error Resume Next
Set trackSheet = trackBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
On Error GoTo 0
If trackSheet Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Worksheet 'sheet1' doesn't exists in workbook, check sheet's name", vbCritical, "Worksheet Name Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

With trackSheet
    firstEmpty = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' get first empty row in column A
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually have error checking before the code I brought here, I didn't put it because it wasn't relevant.